# DHF steps failing post DHF/Gradle upgrade

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

We recently upgraded to DHF 5.8.1 and Gradle 6.4 (from DHF 5.2.0 and Gradle 5.2.1).
After the upgrade we are witnessing some steps/flows failing, but there's no error getting logged. While in the environments where the DHF/Gradle have not been upgraded yet, data is being logged (as JOSN) into a "Jobs" database for the failures, but this is not the case with the upgraded environments.

Do we need to modify some code/settings as part of the DHF upgrade?

Before upgrade below mentioned rewriter files were there in the modules:

```
/data-hub/5/rest-api/rewriter/10-rewriter.xml 
/data-hub/5/rest-api/rewriter/9-rewriter.xml 
/data-hub/5/tracing/10-tracing-rewriter.xml 
/data-hub/5/tracing/9-tracing-rewriter.xml
```

After upgrade:

```
/data-hub/5/data-services/system/createCustomRewriters.api 
/data-hub/5/data-services/system/createCustomRewriters.xqy 
/data-hub/5/rest-api/jobs-rewriter.xml 
/data-hub/5/rest-api/staging-rewriter.xml
```

Can this be an issue?

Comment: We were able to fix the failing steps after upgrading the MarkLogic java client API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to fix the failing steps after upgrading the MarkLogic java client API.